# I want to use python to walk through directories to get to text files and processed them

Tags: python, directory, glob, os.walk

I have many folders in a directory:

```
/home/me/Documents/coverage
```

`/coverage` contains 50 folders all beginning with `H`:

```
/home/me/Documents/coverage/H1   (etc)
```

In each `H***` folder there is a text file which I need to extract data from.

I have been trying to use glob and `os.walk` to use a script that is saved in `/coverage` to walk into each of these `H` folders, open the `.txt` file and process it, but I have had no luck at all.

Would this be a good starting point?  (where `path` = `/coverage`)

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "H*")):
    folder = open(glob.glob(H*))
```

And then try and open the `.txt` file?

Comment: Hmm...works for me, what's the problem? Where's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just gather all the txt files in one shot using glob wildcards.
You can do it like that.

```
import glob
path = "/home/me/Documents/coverage/H*/*.txt"
for filename in glob.glob(path):
    fileStream = open(filename )
```

cheers

Comment: Thank you! I didnt realise you could use the * when naming the path... and then use glob.glob after it!